# Autodesk Eagle 9.6.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 fails to start

Tags: 20.04, crash, error-handling

I used to be able to run Eagle 8.3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 up until recently. Then I updated to 20.04.01 and also upgraded to Egle 9.6.2, but the new install fails to start - after `$./eagle run` I get:

```
[116687:116687:0100/000000.873192:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node channel message
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The `syslog` says:

```
Nov 23 09:05:17 gnome-shell[7679]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400015 specified for 0x4400013.
Nov 23 09:05:17  kernel: [127935.866677] Chrome_IOThread[116762]: segfault at 68 ip 00007fa13e236c07 sp 00007fa0f0ff7eb8 error 6 in libnss3.so[7fa13e1f6000+f0000]
Nov 23 09:05:17 kernel: [127935.866684] Code: 4f 0b fc ff 4c 89 e7 45 31 e4 e8 24 0d fc ff 48 83 c4 08 4c 89 e0 5b 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 <f0> 83 47 68 01 c3 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 41 55 41 89 d5 41 54 49 89
```

The old install also fails but the error is related to QT issues.

I looked through the [Autodesk forums](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/can-t-run-eagle-on-debian-10-testing/m-p/8318376/highlight/false#M17111) and tried the solutions as well as the [GLX solution listed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180487/unable-to-run-eagle-9-5-1-on-ubuntu-18-04). None helped.

Any advise will be appreciated!

**UPDATE 1**
I have now tried to run the executable with `sudo` and that worked! Looks like it is a permissions issue - just not sure what it is that I need to set-up to get the system running as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Create a desktoplink

*[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=Eagle

Name[de_DE]=Eagle

Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it

Exec=env LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 /home/YOUR_PC/eagle-9.6.2/./eagle run

Icon=/home/YOUR_PC/eagle-9.6./bin/eagle-logo.png

Categories=Development;

Terminal=false*

And eagle start

Comment: Unfortunately this is a duplicate of the GLX solution... and it does not work.